# integrate oraclejet in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, oracle-jet

Trying to have oraclejet wotking in a nuxt.jet basic project.

I generated  a simple nuxt project and was working ok .
Then added oraclejet  and typed :

```
npm install --save oraclejet
```

Then added in nuxt.config.js :

```
modules: [
     'oraclejet'
  ],
```

Then running

```
npm run dev
```

There is no errors starting but when i go to http://127.0.0.1:3000 i'm getting :

```
Cannot GET /
```

without any errors

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think oraclejet and nuxt should be used together. They both have some overlapping features. If you're sure though, you should know that when you run `ojet serve` instead of `npm run dev`, the cli sets up various folders and files in the web folder, like the oj library, oj css files, and makes references to these locations in both js and html files. You would need to configure all that manually if you're primarily using nuxt.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/jet/5.2/develop/getting-started-oracle-jet-web-application-development.html#GUID-E7F0C484-197A-40EB-997D-5DE95C9F5032) might give you some idea about ojet configuration.